# Is there a way to reset a user's secret question if they know neither the answer nor their password?

Tags: administration, security, user-admin

A user forgot their password. I have admin rights in the org so I reset their password. They then informed me that they have also forgotten the answer to their secret question.

I know that you can navigate to your own user settings and change your secret question and its answer, so I logged in as her through the user list as described [here](http://blogs.salesforce.com/product/2012/06/log-in-as-any-user-without-first-having-access-granted-new-feature-in-summer-12.html). Unfortunately your old password is also needed to change this.

The user has also tried several combinations of answers with lower case and upper case letters.

I've found a few articles like [this](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005251&language=en_US) that don't give much information about resetting the security answer - "If you do not remember the answer to your secret question you should contact your System Administrator".

Please note this is also in a sandbox environment so if I'm totally out of options, as an alternative I can delete and recreate the user, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the secret answer with an admin password reset. The screen allows them to set a new password AND secret question/answer at the time. They are not being asked to confirm their old secret question/answer. Also, you can't delete users. Once created, the user will exist until the entire sandbox is refreshed from production.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I didn't realise you couldn't delete users from the sandbox.

Comment: The user responded saying they had received an e-mail with a temporary password and was able to log in with that. It didn't ask them for a secret question and answer at all.

Comment: They should still set a new answer as soon as possible so they don't have to bother you each time they need a password reset.

Answer (score 2):

A quote from [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gmhyAAA):

> In this scenerio, you can do 1 thing call salesforce.com customer
>   support and tell them your user name. They will ask you 1 or 2
>   questions to verify your identity and they will reset the password for
>   you.
>
> Salesforce Support Contact numbers are listed at-
>   https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000001000

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. The user responded saying they had received an e-mail with a temporary password and was able to log in with that. It didn't ask them for a secret question and answer at all.

I'm not sure if this is new functionality or possibly only sandbox behaviour.